# How to return only needed values without 0's and nulls in this question?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this question that I have been tackling for a while.

"The method should return an array containing the elements that are divisible by a certain number" in this case the target which is 5.

Here is my solution

```
public static int[] Divisible(int[] array, int target){
    int[] answer = new int[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
       if (array[i] % target == 0){
           answer[i] = array[i];
       }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

assuming my input is 
int[] input = {5,3,6,10};
my output will be [5,0,0,10].

My desired output should be [5,10].

please, How do I get rid of the zeros

Comment: Using an `ArrayList` would help.  Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: Is your `target` parameter in the example `5`? You could do what @markspace suggested, and remove any "zeroes" from the list.

Comment: No. The question specified that the method should accept an array of numbers. Is there a way arraylist can be used here instead? Sorry for the odd question, I am only a beginner.

Comment: Yes, you could use an `ArrayList` for the `answers` then call `toArray` to get an array to return.  But you'll need to ask your instructor if that's OK.  Otherwise, ask you instructor what is needed, because if you don't know the number of answers then you have to resize the array and that's going to be difficult for a beginner.

Comment: yes, 5 is the target @xamser7

Comment: `public static int[] Divisi(int[] array, int target){
        int[] answer = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            ArrayList<Integer> yes = new ArrayList<>();
           if (array[i] % target == 0){
               yes.add(array[i]);
               answer = yes.toArray();
           }
        }
        return answer;
    }`

I did something like this which is still giving errors now

Comment: You could count the number of non-zeros in `answer`, create another array with the size of that number, put the non-zeros in and `return` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
public static int[] Divisible(int[] array, int target){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] % target == 0){
            list.add(array[i]);
        }
    }
    int[] ints = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to fill the answer array from the bottom, and then truncate it to exactly the size you need.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   if (array[i] % target == 0){
       answer[j++] = array[i];
   }
}
return Arrays.copyOf(answer, j);
```

Arrays is a standard Java utility class.

If you're not allowed to use the Arrays utility class then the last line can be replaced by:

```
int[] answer2 = new int[j];
for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
   answer2[i] = answer[i];
return answer2;
```

This feels a little clunky to me but it satisfies the apparent requirements to use simple arrays.

Comment: You took the time to write real code, that often gets more praise, but hey, it is also more work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- you can use an ArrayList internally, as that can grow dynamically (you just keep adding the values you are interested in, done). If you have to return an array, you can easily do that based on your filled list.
- when going only with arrays you can simply do 2 passes: first create that large array and fill it. Then count the non zero entries! Create a new array with the smaller length, and then copy over all non zero elements manually.

Comment: Oh, I like the two-pass idea better than my copy-the-array suggestion, at least for reasonably-sized input.  But I at first misunderstood you.  Pass 1: count elements satisfying the criteria. Pass 2: copy those elements into a correctly-sized array.  You don't need to allocate the 'larger' answer array if you don't mind doing the ```% target``` computation twice.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest and the most quickest way to go about this is, you can change the array to an ArrayList and then use .toArray() method to get it back as a primitive array when returning.

```
public static Integer[] Divisible(int[] array, int target){ 
    List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){ 
        if (array[i] % target == 0) {
            answer.add(array[i]); // pushing to list only if the number is divisible
        } 
    } 
    return answer.toArray(new Integer[0]); // converting the list to an array before returning
}
```

If you want a list of unique numbers use Set instead of a List.

```
Set<Integer> answer = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method stated by @GhostCat but it made me change the code entirely. This is my new code

```
public static Object[] Divisi(int[] array, int target){
    ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] % target == 0){
            answer.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return answer.toArray();
}
```

This gave me the desired answer but how else can i do this without converting to object

Comment: You have to pass an empty array object as stated in my answer.

Comment: I used your method but it kept saying "toArray
(T[])
in List cannot be applied
to
(int[])"

Comment: Oops sorry my bad. It would only cast to the Integer object. We can change it to Integer instead of int

Comment: returning Object[] is not nice when you know the contents are Integers.  There is a form of toArray that will avoid that.  But the OPs original formulation used primitive ints, so it's not clear whether solutions are at liberty to use Integer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the primitive int, I have conformed to using Integer instead.
Here is my solution.

```
public static Integer[] divisible(Integer[] array, int target) {

    int j = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % target == 0) {
            j++;
            list.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    Integer answer[] = new Integer[j];
    answer = list.toArray(answer);

    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate counter for the result array and keep incrementing the counter if the number is divisible by the target.

Something like this :

```
int[] result=new int[array.length];
int resultindex=0; //create a separate counter
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(array[i]%target==0)
    {
        result[resultindex]=array[i];
        ++resultindex; //update the counter
    }
}
```

Comment: But the result array still has elements "at the end" (i.e., from the final resultindex to .length-1) which need to be eliminated/  Since arrays cannot be resized, it is then necessary to copy into a new exact-size array.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.